# How to Count rows without Header After filtering the table using the VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets in excel file with two tables:

**Sheet 1:** 
Having the table of the data to be filtered

**Sheet 2:** 
Having the summary page that shows the number of Rows to a specific filter.
It have a filter control panel

I have created a code on the VB and assign it to a button to be clickable and my code to filter the table is:

Sheets(ItemsSheet).Select

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=Menu"

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=Submenu"

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=Phase_Column, Criteria1:= _
    Array(Phase, "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

When I Execute this code, it redirect me to the Sheet 1 and the filter is applied successfully.

**Question:**

1. How Can I calculate the number of rows located in the [Sheet1]?
2. How to display the number of rows in a cell located in the [Sheet2] after filter?
3. How to execute the above code without redirect to the [Sheet1]?

**Image for your reference:**

[image]

Comment: If all you want to know is how many rows you could use COUNTIFS rather than vb code

Comment: I have large number of criteria so it works with me to do it in a VBA code, I agree that countifs is much faster but for reliable code I used to do it as a VBA Code.

Comment: In this case I can use the cell in both ways with a single code, pasting the number of rows for a specific filter and a button that can take me directly to the filtered page.

Comment: `Aggregate` can count number of visible cells (by ignoring blanks

Comment: Thanks for helping it works now :). Any help regarding the Auto filter without redirecting to the filtered sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I did many Searches on this Question.  I have find a solution for that:

Add the below Code after executing the Filter Code:

**Code:**

```
Dim mycount As Long

mycount = Intersect(Columns(1), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

MsgBox mycount
```

**Result:**

You will get all rows that are visible after applying the filter.

Regards